# Bottom of site cut off/ scroll bar

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, divi

I seem to have an issue that can be replicated sometimes but not always.

The bottom of the homepage, find us section is cropped off with a scroll bar added to the right and bottom. I have tried a few things and can’t seem to shift it

http://aquila-k9.flywheelsites.com/

New to this and learning so appreciate any direction.

Answer (score 0):

In the div or section having the scrollbar set

```
 overflow-x: hidden;
```

I can explain the answer more efficiently if share your code.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for coming back to me. I haven’t added any code myself at this point .. only used the do I visual builder

Comment: I didn't get what you are saying . Sorry . What does it mean do I visual builder?

Comment: So I am working with the divi theme on Wordpress and within that, there is a drag and drop builder

Comment: ok then I don't have knowledge about wordpress. Sorry.